# Migrate Oracle XMLTYPE Data to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle, data-migration, xmltype

I have a table in Oracle which contains a data type of XMLTYPE. Can anyone suggest a way of extracting this data out to a file and then loading it into Postgres? I'm struggling to find a way as part of my data migration from Oracle to Postgres. Unfortunately there is no connectivity between source and target so I can't use any foreign tables. Using ora2pg as well is a no go as we will potentially have millions of records it just won't perform.

I have set the below up as a test scenario but I just can't get the data out:

```
CREATE TABLE xml_test (id number, xml xmltype);
INSERT INTO xml_test VALUES (1, XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT '<?xml version="1.0"?><book><title>Manual</title><chapter>...</chapter></book>'));
INSERT INTO xml_test VALUES (11, XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT '<?xml version="1.0"?><book><title>Manual</title><chapter>SOME TEXT</chapter></book>'));
INSERT INTO xml_test VALUES (111, XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT '<?xml version="1.0"?><book><title>Manual</title><chapter>"SOME MORE TEXT"</chapter></book>'));
INSERT INTO xml_test values (2, xmltype.createxml('<subject><name>test</name><list><li>a</li><li>b</li></list></subject>'));
INSERT INTO xml_test values (3, xmltype.createxml('<subject><name>test</name><list><li>a</li></list></subject>'));
INSERT INTO xml_test VALUES 
  (4, xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Warehouse>
    <WarehouseId>1</WarehouseId>
    <WarehouseName>Southlake, Texas</WarehouseName>
    <Building>Owned</Building>
    <Area>25000</Area>
    <Docks>2</Docks>
    <DockType>Rear load</DockType>
    <WaterAccess>true</WaterAccess>
    <RailAccess>N</RailAccess>
    <Parking>Street</Parking>
    <VClearance>10</VClearance>
  </Warehouse>'));
```

Now I have this data in my Oracle table, what's the best way to migrate it into my Postgres database?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a foreign table, then use `insert into postgres_table (...) select ... from oracle_table`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use a foreign table, there is no connectivity between source and target. I was hoping their would be a way to extract the contents to a file, then transfer the file to the target server and load the data in.

Answer (score 0):

try [ora2pg](http://www.ora2pg.com/) the tool support XMLTYPE Migration

Comment: ora2pg is great, but when migrating a lot of data it just doesn't perform. If it was just a few records I would use it but due to the data volumne, hundreds of thousands to millions of records, extracting the data out and then loading it in would be faster than the insert statements generated by ora2pg.

Comment: try oracle_fdw, even with no connectivité your can setup a postgres database beside the oracle database
https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/using-foreign-data-wrappers-access-remote-postgresql-and-oracle-databases

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to encode the XML data as base64. Then export it as a csv file and import it back into the Postgres database.

Function to encode base64:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_base64( fil  IN CLOB )
RETURN CLOB
AS
   res CLOB;
   buf VARCHAR2(19200);
   pos PLS_INTEGER := 1;
   amt PLS_INTEGER := 19200;
   b64 VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
   DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( res, FALSE );
   DBMS_LOB.OPEN( res, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE );
   LOOP
      DBMS_LOB.READ( fil, amt, pos, buf );
      pos := pos + amt;
      b64 := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2( UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE( UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW( buf )));
      DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( res, LENGTH( b64 ), b64 );
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      DBMS_LOB.CLOSE( res );
      RETURN res;
END get_base64;
/
```

Export to csv:

```
DECLARE
   l_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
   l_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(location => 'TEMP_DIR', filename => 'test.csv', open_mode => 'w', max_linesize => 32767);
   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE( l_file, '"id"; "xml_base64"' );
   
   FOR cur IN ( SELECT id,
                       get_base64(xmltype.getclobval(xml)) AS xml_base64
                  FROM xml_test )
   LOOP
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE( l_file, '"'||cur.id ||'"; "' || cur.xml_base64 ||'"' );
   END LOOP;
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE( l_file );
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE( l_file );
END;
/
```

Import it into Postgres. You need an additional text column.
Then decode the base64 encoded text and parse it as XML.

```
UPDATE xml_test
   SET xml = XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT convert_from(decode(xml_base64, 'base64'), 'UTF8'));
```

This should work. Please check out if it is also performant enough.